# Have I just ruined my Minecraft save?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a Minecraft world using Mo's Creatures, Balkon's Weapon Mod and Rei's Minimap about a month ago. I updated Minecraft to 1.6 so I could test out the new features. The next day I accidentally loaded my modded save. Have I lost all my items from these mods?

Comment: In a word: yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you load these saves, any modded items are lost, unless you have a backup you can restore from.

Comment: Damn, I knew I should have made a backup!

Comment: ForgeEssentials has am automatic backup thingy.